# Why is gulp in Bootstrap 5-SASS Starter Kit not compiling style.scss?

Tags: sass, drupal, gulp

I just installed a fresh new D10 site, and went through the process of installing SASS, Bootstrap Barrio & Bootstrap 5 - SASS Starter Kit,and followed the [instructions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-themes/bootstrap-45-barrio-sass-starter-kit/installation) of creating a subtheme, but when I installed the subtheme and set it as default, I got this:
[port20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyHOb.png)

When I checked the subtheme folder, the style.css was blank. Clearly gulp didn't process the style.scss file in the subtheme/scss folder.

I spent almost 2 days trying to find anything similar, but to no avail. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone faces the same problem, I opened a support request on the Bootstrap_SASS issue tracker regarding this issue, and somebody already posted a [workaround solution](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_sass/issues/3365211#comment-15097425)